# PHP preg_match to match season Numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the code below to grab the Season Number from a string.
But it doesnt work OK as the season number is before any `"Season"` Words.

I tried to put `(\d+)\s*` in front of the pattern but then the code it did not return anything.

How can i fix my preg_match to return the season number if it is `before or after the "Season" words?`

```
$a = 'The Simpson 11 Season';

if ( preg_match( "/(Season|Stagione|S|T)\s*(\d+)/i", $a, $matches ) )
{
    print_r( $matches );
}
```

Comment: What are the exact results do you need? Just the digits? Or do you need the exact groups in the resulting array?

Comment: yes. Just the number 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To get the substring with the number**  use

```
$a = 'I need the 11 Stagione';
if ( preg_match( "/\b(Season|Stagione|S|T)\s*\d+|\d+\s*(?1)\b/i", $a, $matches ) )
{
    print_r( $matches[0] );
}
```

See [a PHP demo](http://rextester.com/OHZWW96185).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(Season|Stagione|S|T)` - Group 1, any of the alternative substrings
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace
- `(?1)` - Group 1 pattern
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: I'm sorry confused. I want to have also the "Stagione" string too. For example in the above one i would like to have back the "11 Season". My bad! :) But thanks for your answer it works awesome for what i said in the beggining

Comment: @OhGodWhy I edited the answer with the third solution.

Comment: Perfect. It works awesome. 1 More thing though. How to match the words in order?

Assuming i had "$a = 'I need thes 11 Stagione';"

It will match "s 11" and not the "11 Stagione". But "s" is after the "Stagione" in my matching words. Thank you so much

Comment: Use whole word matching with `\b`.